# Ошибка при запуске сайта на OpenServer. Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'getConnection' not found

Tags: php, веб-программирование, openserver

У меня возникает ошибка . Она появляется при запуске сайта на OpenServer. Там указано что клас не найден.И нужен ли вообще этот класс?

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'getConnection' not found in D:\OpenServer\OpenServer\domains\Internetstor\models\Category.php:16 Stack trace: #0 D:\OpenServer\OpenServer\domains\Internetstor\controllers\SiteController.php(15): Category::getCategoriesList() #1 D:\OpenServer\OpenServer\domains\Internetstor\components\Router.php(80): SiteController->actionIndex() #2 D:\OpenServer\OpenServer\domains\Internetstor\index.php(18): Router->run() #3 {main} thrown in D:\OpenServer\OpenServer\domains\Internetstor\models\Category.php on line 16

Вот код Category:

```
<?php

/**
 * Класс Category - модель для работы с категориями товаров
 */
class Category
{

    /**
     * Возвращает массив категорий для списка на сайте
     * @return array <p>Массив с категориями</p>
     */
    public static function getCategoriesList()
    {
        // Соединение с БД
        $db = include getConnection::getConnection;

        // Запрос к БД
        $result = $db->query('SELECT id, name FROM category WHERE status = "1" ORDER BY sort_order, name ASC');

        // Получение и возврат результатов
        $i = 0;
        $categoryList = array();
        while ($row = $result->fetch()) {
            $categoryList[$i]['id'] = $row['id'];
            $categoryList[$i]['name'] = $row['name'];
            $i++;
        }
        return $categoryList;
    }

    /**
     * Возвращает массив категорий для списка в админпанели <br/>
     * (при этом в результат попадают и включенные и выключенные категории)
     * @return array <p>Массив категорий</p>
     */
    public static function getCategoriesListAdmin()
    {
        // Соединение с БД
        $db = Db::getConnection();

        // Запрос к БД
        $result = $db->query('SELECT id, name, sort_order, status FROM category ORDER BY sort_order ASC');

        // Получение и возврат результатов
        $categoryList = array();
        $i = 0;
        while ($row = $result->fetch()) {
            $categoryList[$i]['id'] = $row['id'];
            $categoryList[$i]['name'] = $row['name'];
            $categoryList[$i]['sort_order'] = $row['sort_order'];
            $categoryList[$i]['status'] = $row['status'];
            $i++;
        }
        return $categoryList;
    }

    /**
     * Удаляет категорию с заданным id
     * @param integer $id
     * @return boolean <p>Результат выполнения метода</p>
     */
    public static function deleteCategoryById($id)
    {
        // Соединение с БД
        $db = Db::getConnection();

        // Текст запроса к БД
        $sql = 'DELETE FROM category WHERE id = :id';

        // Получение и возврат результатов. Используется подготовленный запрос
        $result = $db->prepare($sql);
        $result->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        return $result->execute();
    }

    /**
     * Редактирование категории с заданным id
     * @param integer $id <p>id категории</p>
     * @param string $name <p>Название</p>
     * @param integer $sortOrder <p>Порядковый номер</p>
     * @param integer $status <p>Статус <i>(включено "1", выключено "0")</i></p>
     * @return boolean <p>Результат выполнения метода</p>
     */
    public static function updateCategoryById($id, $name, $sortOrder, $status)
    {
        // Соединение с БД
        $db = Db::getConnection();

        // Текст запроса к БД
        $sql = "UPDATE category
            SET 
                name = :name, 
                sort_order = :sort_order, 
                status = :status
            WHERE id = :id";

        // Получение и возврат результатов. Используется подготовленный запрос
        $result = $db->prepare($sql);
        $result->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $result->bindParam(':name', $name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $result->bindParam(':sort_order', $sortOrder, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $result->bindParam(':status', $status, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        return $result->execute();
    }

    /**
     * Возвращает категорию с указанным id
     * @param integer $id <p>id категории</p>
     * @return array <p>Массив с информацией о категории</p>
     */
    public static function getCategoryById($id)
    {
        // Соединение с БД
        $db = Db::getConnection();

        // Текст запроса к БД
        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM category WHERE id = :id';

        // Используется подготовленный запрос
        $result = $db->prepare($sql);
        $result->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);

        // Указываем, что хотим получить данные в виде массива
        $result->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        // Выполняем запрос
        $result->execute();

        // Возвращаем данные
        return $result->fetch();
    }

    /**
     * Возвращает текстое пояснение статуса для категории :<br/>
     * <i>0 - Скрыта, 1 - Отображается</i>
     * @param integer $status <p>Статус</p>
     * @return string <p>Текстовое пояснение</p>
     */
    public static function getStatusText($status)
    {
        switch ($status) {
            case '1':
                return 'Отображается';
                break;
            case '0':
                return 'Скрыта';
                break;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Добавляет новую категорию
     * @param string $name <p>Название</p>
     * @param integer $sortOrder <p>Порядковый номер</p>
     * @param integer $status <p>Статус <i>(включено "1", выключено "0")</i></p>
     * @return boolean <p>Результат добавления записи в таблицу</p>
     */
    public static function createCategory($name, $sortOrder, $status)
    {
        // Соединение с БД
        $db = Db::getConnection();

        // Текст запроса к БД
        $sql = 'INSERT INTO category (name, sort_order, status) '
                . 'VALUES (:name, :sort_order, :status)';

        // Получение и возврат результатов. Используется подготовленный запрос
        $result = $db->prepare($sql);
        $result->bindParam(':name', $name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $result->bindParam(':sort_order', $sortOrder, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $result->bindParam(':status', $status, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        return $result->execute();
    }

}
```

Вот код getConection:

```
<?php

/**
 * 
 */
class getConnection
{

    /**
     * Устанавливает соединение с базой данных
     * @return \PDO <p>Объект класса PDO для работы с БД</p>
     */
    public static function getConnection()
    {
        // Получаем параметры подключения из файла
        $paramsPath = ROOT . '/config/db_params.php';
        $params = include($paramsPath);

        // Устанавливаем соединение
        $dsn = "mysql:host={$params['host']};dbname={$params['dbname']}";
        $db = new PDO($dsn, $params['user'], $params['password']);

        // Задаем кодировку
        $db->exec("set names utf8");

        return $db;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Первое, что необходимо исправить - наименование методов и классов. Классы, по хорошему, именуются с большой буквы. Совпадений наименований классов, методов, свойств и атрибутов быть не должно.

У вас получается, что не подключаете файл самого класса `getConection`. Надо использовать подключение этого файла перед тем, как использовать его методы.

То есть, вам надо сделать `require_once` файла класса `getConection`, затем только вы можете использовать ваши конструкции.